# How can I hide the title in a custom page made with hook_menu?

Tags: 6, routes

I need to hide the title on a custom page created using hook_menu. I don't have a nid, so probably I can't use one of the existing modules to do that.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mypath'] = array(
    'title' => 'My title',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content')
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I know this could be done using this css

```
body#pid-mypath {
  h1.title {
    display: none
  }
}
```

but I want to know if there are other alternatives. I'm working with Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if processed on time but I would try using [drupal_set_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_set_title/6). And making sure you have an if statement around the h1 or h2. So use drupal_set_title to create empty title and use:

```
if(!empty($title)){
echo '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>';
}
```

Comment: Worked with drupal_set_title('') on the mymodule_page_callback function. Thanks.